# How to notify user that they can't run/install Laravel application because of file permission of storage/bootstrap directory?

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, requirements

So I've been working on this open source application called [Faveo Helpdesk](https://github.com/ladybirdweb/faveo-helpdesk), which is built in Laravel. It has installer which checks server environment for requirements of Laravel and other required PHP extensions. It also has a check to verify permission for storage and bootstrap directories as they should be writable by web server according to [Laravel Requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#server-requirements).

The problem is the installer itself runs on Laravel and uses Laravel routes to show installation steps. And if the permissions are not correct on server it will not run and show installation steps as Laravel will not run in that case.

As many users face the same issue with the application and each time we need to guide/help them for checking and updating the permissions manually. I want to catch the exception and handle it by redirecting user to a normal php file where I'll show them the message to correct their file permission. Currently it simply shows browser error page giving no idea about the problem to users.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: I think it's good idea to check files permissions on your public/index.php file before running laravel bootstrap. You should use pure php and have a unique view file for showing error.

Comment: @train_fox, I was thinking to implement the same way but I have some doubts. Will it not execute the same code for checking file permission in every request even after the user gave correct permission to required directories?

Comment: Right. I'm thinking on two different approachs. First, base on what i told before, add script to your installer code to remove check permission code from index.php. second approach will be have a separate file like installer.php to check permission then redirect to your main route.

Comment: Second approach looks more appropriate as it will first check the requirement in normal PHP then handle the control to Laravel

Comment: Yes, also i saw this on other open source project like prestashop.